# mirror relativelayout in android, no update

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, mirror

I want to mirror the app an use a customized relativeLayout class for the root view.
It works fine, but I habe one problem. If I refresh something in one element, that is mirrored not on the physical Location, it won't be updated. So I have to correct the coordinate, which should be updated, but I don't know how.

```
 package de.etestdriver.everclock.gui;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Point;
 import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class HUDRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout{

public HUDRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false); 
}

public HUDRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false); 
}

public HUDRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false); 
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.scale(-1,1, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas); 
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
event.setLocation( getWidth()-event.getX(), event.getY());
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event); 
}


}
```